# Typing a function identically to another function with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, generics, types

I am wrapping a function from a library and want the wrapper function to have the same typing as the wrapped function, so that the generics and arguments can be passed through.

The function I am looking to wrap is from the apollo library, named useQuery.

It's declaration looks like this:

```
export declare function useQuery<TData = any, TVariables = OperationVariables>(query: DocumentNode | TypedDocumentNode<TData, TVariables>, options?: QueryHookOptions<TData, TVariables>): QueryResult<TData, TVariables>;
```

I want to write a function that wraps useQuery as so:

```
function wrapper<*generics*>(*args*) {
    ...
    return useQuery<*generics*>(*args*);
}
```

Can I somehow provide the generics and arguments without having to import the appropriate types?

Can this be done implicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not currently a way to do this in TypeScript if `wrapper` is declared as a [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).  You can get the type of `useQuery` with [the `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator), generics and all... but you can't [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the whole function statement as conforming to it; you'd have to annotate the parameters and return type separately, and the generics explicitly.  There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#22063](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063) asking for support for such function statement annotations, but for now they're not part of the language.

On the other hand, if you are okay declaring `wrapper` as a variable or constant with a function-typed value, then you can do this easily like this:

```
const wrapper: typeof useQuery = (...args) => {
  // do other stuff here
  return useQuery(...args);
}
```

There's no explicit, manual typing of the generics, parameters, or return types here.  And it compiles with no error, indicating that the compiler [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) infers `args` to be a rest parameter of the proper generic type, and that the function returns a value of the proper generic type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCKz1QJ5wC+cAZlBCHAOQACAhpADaMQD0Axo8OgHYxUAoAewg9U8AO5QGYXAC44MPLIgkUGbLgIBeOAAoAdEbpQA5qgCUcbQD5EAuHFas4J8woDaDpy7gBHHHwFABEIdmQQXhgAOQgAE3Q4AB84ABVldDjQ8Mi+WISAHlTguhg6ABo0gDUTYDoAI0Z0VBtK72dHCDAYYFFUAH4FTXwACQgIAGsAeW7esSKSssrUmqg6xua7FOQeBJJgHkz2lwBdbyh0GGQoHnUsQLxDYzNLAG5juAvUZEYYIYeAErNH4wBalCrVWoNJotASEIRAA)

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this. Typescript provides a set of utility types which makes this type of function wrapping, possible.

```
function wrapper(...args: Parameters<typeof useQuery>) {
  // Do something here
  return useQuery(...args);
}
```

See [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype). You may also be interested in [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype).

`ReturnType` wasn't used in the solution because typescript is able to infer the return type provided `return useQuery (...)` is the last thing returned in the function.